# Populate CustomUI for Excel 365 Backstage

Tags: xml, vb.net, office365

I am developing a version of the CustomUI utility for my own purposes. I started with code from MSDN which sets up the original CustomUI element for Office 2007, but I can’t find how to implement the backstage in this version.

The original [code taken from MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Excel-2010-Adding-Custom-faa896ec/sourcecode?fileId=49144&pathId=1090930665) is:

```vb
Using document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, True) 
  ' You can only have a single ribbon extensibility part. 
  ' If the part doesn't exist, add it. 
  Dim part = document.RibbonExtensibilityPart 
  If part Is Nothing Then 
    part = document.AddRibbonExtensibilityPart 
  End If 
  part.CustomUI = New CustomUI(customUIContent) 
  part.CustomUI.Save() 
End Using
```

If `customUIcontent` contains XML with `<backstage>` tags (using `xmlns= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"`), this code fails.

I used the original CustomUI utility to insert the sample backstage into a workbook. On inspection of the XML (in a watch), I find an additional element `RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart`. I tried to replicate the original code, substituting `RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart` for `RibbonExtensibilityPart` – but this failed on the 
`part.CustomUI = New CustomUI(customUIContent)` line.

On further examination of the XML content in my sample, I find innerXML and outerXML which have variants of the original XML where the tags have `"mso14"` prefix (which is presumably why CustomUI shows CustomUI14.xml separate from CustomUI12.xml parts).

I have searched extensively for help on how to populate the `RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart` element with my XML, but failed to find the right syntax.

Can anyone tell me the proper method to populate the `RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart` element, please?

I am using the Open XML 2.5 SDK with VS 2012.

Many thanks.

P.S.: I posted this question in ericwhite.com earlier today; repeating here to get wider audience. :-)

Comment: You should include the XML snippets you talk about, as well as the exact error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

There are two version of custom UI for the Office. The first version is under the name space http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui and second version is under the new name space  http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui.

The backstage view is introduced from Office 2010 and we need to use the new name space. And in the Open XML 2.5, we should use RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart to insert ribbon XML under the new version name space.

Here is an sample that used Open XML 2.5 to add a tab in the Office backstage view for your reference:

```
    public void Main()
    {

        string docName = @"C:\book1.xlsx";
        string customUIContent = "<customUI xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui\">"
                               + "<backstage>"
                               + "<tab id = \"customTab1\" label = \"customTab1\" ></tab>"
                               + "</backstage>"
                               + "</customUI >";
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
        {
            if (document.RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart == null)
            {
                document.AddRibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart();
                document.RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart.CustomUI = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.CustomUI.CustomUI(customUIContent);
                document.RibbonAndBackstageCustomizationsPart.CustomUI.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I had changed the XML to reflect the new namespace, but I hadn't noticed the change library version. Much appreciated.